Robot tv show I saw in the 90s, teen inherits self aware robots
If I recall correctly this show was on TV as a Saturday morning cartoon in New Zealand in the early-mid 90s.
The protagonist was a teen who had inherited his father's collection of robots; this was not unusual in the setting, many people had robots.
However his father's robots were self aware and able to act independently which was, literally, unheard of. To the point where one of the few scenes I remember clearly is the robots discussing the fact that they absolutely couldn't get into trouble over some incident because everyone "knows" they're only able to follow orders.
The thing that stood out for me about this series, and separated it from Transformers etc... that were also on TV at that time, was that the robots were human scale rather than towering over the humans they shared their world with.

Any plot points? Were there any fights, like in transformers?

@YaroslavKornachevskyi That's a big part of the problem apart from the protagonist getting into trouble over something and the robots getting told to go home, then having the discussion about how they couldn't get in trouble (even though they were at fault maybe?) I don't remember anything else about it clearly, not even the animation style let alone the storyline.

The Botz Master, maybe?

I’ve never seen the show. If it is actually what you are looking for, then you would probably write up a better answer than I.

But you would be better able to write where the show matches your description than I, and I don’t really care about points.  But I will be happy to try if you give me a day or two.

The Bots Master is a 1993 television show and (abortive) toyline.
The storyline occurs in 2025 A.D. where young genius engineer “ZZ” Zulander has created a series of hyper-intelligent robots that revolutionize the world.
Unfortunately, the company he works for turns out to be Evil™, and tries to take over the world using a master control chip to control the robots. To fight back, ZZ creates a special force of truly sentient robots, “the B.O.Y.Z.Z.” Much of the plot involves various people trying to learn ZZ’s secret.
Here is an image shamelessly yoinked from the TV Tropes page:

I do not (yet) know which episode features the conversation mentioned in the question, but you can apparently view full episodes on YouTube.
⟶ Disney evidently owns the rights to the program these days, but I do not know if it is still possible to buy episodes.

That's the one, I recognise the animation style, didn't remember it being quite so campy but it was the 90s.

I honestly don’t know how I found it, lol. I’ve never seen it. If I find the episode you were talking about I’ll add it. I suspect it’ll be one where the BOYZZ go back to RM Corp to try to stop manufacture of the Krang chip or something...
